# imap_append with accents in folder

Tags: php, internationalization, imap

I have a mailbox (in French) with the following structure:

```
me@example.com
|
|_Inbox
|_Brouillons (="Drafts")
|_Éléments envoyés (="Sent items")
|_Éléments supprimés (="Deleted items")
```

My users usually check their emails with a webmail or a mail client. But sometimes I need to add messages manually in the "Sent" folder, which has the name `Éléments envoyés`, containing several **accents** and a **whitespace**.

Here is the relevant PHP code:

```
$imap_stream = imap_open("{imap.example.com:143/tls}", "me@example.com", "password");
imap_append($imap_stream, "{imap.example.com:143/tls}Éléments envoyés",
...
```

The above code does not work. If I try with a folder without accents, like `Brouillons`, the messages are correctly copied.

Could it be an encoding problem? If I check the properties with Thunderbird, the location is shown as

```
imap://me%40example.com@imap.example.com/%26AMk-l%26AOk-ments%20envoy%26AOk-s
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See rfc 3501, folders are encoded in a modified utf7 encoding, which is basically utf8 over base64. You should see if your library has an encoder for that.

Comment: @Max: I had no idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Max's comment, I knew what to look for, and I found [beetstra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461797/994820).

The solution is then:

```
$utf7_folder_name = mb_convert_encoding("Éléments envoyés", "UTF7-IMAP", "UTF-8");
$imap_stream = imap_open("{imap.example.com:143/tls}", "me@example.com", "password");
imap_append($imap_stream, "{imap.example.com:143/tls}".$utf7_folder_name,
...
```